# access to a variables into a json code

Tags: php, json

I have this code:

```
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "status": 200,
    "msg": "OK",
    "result": {
       "72fA-_Lq8Ak3": {
            "id": "72fA-_Lq8Ak3",
            "status": 200,
            "name": "The quick brown fox.txt",
            "size": 123456789012,
            "sha1": "2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12",
            "content_type": "plain/text",
        },
        "72fA-_Lq8Ak4": {
            "id": "72fA-_Lq8Ak4",
            "status": 500,
            "name": "The quick brown fox.txt",
            "size": false,
            "sha1": "2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12",
            "content_type": "plain/text",
        },
        "72fA-_Lq8Ak5": {
            "id": "72fA-_Lq8Ak5",
            "status": 404,
            "name": false,
            "size": false,
            "sha1": false,
            "content_type": false,
        },
        "72fA-_Lq8Ak6": {
            "id": "72fA-_Lq8Ak6",
            "status": 451,
            "name": "The quick brown fox.txt",
            "size": 123456789012,
            "sha1": "2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12",
            "content_type": "plain/text",
        }
    }
}
```

How can i access with php in result->72fA-_Lq8Ak3->status?

I have used this code:

```
$control=json_decode($output); $stat=$control->{'result'}->{"".$ll}->{'status'};
```

But it returns me nothing (empty). How can i take the code in status?
In the variables `$ll` there's the code `72fA-_Lq8Ak3` but it doesn't read the values of variables. the real question is: How can i insert the variables as a string that the program can read?

Thanks to the reply. 
Sorry for my english but I'm french.

UPDATE:

i have already this output, the output that server returns to me (after the changes) is this:

```
{
    "status":200,
    "msg":"OK",
    "result":{
            "TgaB4CzkhaM":{ "id":"TgaB4CzkhaM",
                            "status":200,
                            "name":"esempio2.avi.mp4",
                            "size":"10391713",
                            "sha1":"125d4aa4c039cdf5686d565e705e38cbab966550",
                            "content_type":"video\/mp4",
                            "cstatus":"0"
                        }
            }
}
```

how can i enter on

```
results-> TgaB4CzkhaM -> status?
```

thanks

Comment: use `json_decode($output, true)` it will make life easier for you ;)

Comment: Nothing to do with the property access. `print json_last_error_msg();` and use some linting tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect bad json data in PHP json\_decode()?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2348152)

Comment: `Error: Parse error on line 11:
...e": "plain/text",  },  "72fA-_Lq8Ak4":
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', got '}'`

Comment: Cannot have a trailing comma after the last property of an object. **How did you create this JSON String??**

Comment: If you cannot fix your JSON String to be valid JSON then there is nothing you can do but packup and go home

Comment: @RiggsFolly  . correct  .. the comma after  content type values must be removed

Comment: Do YOU create the JSON String on your server or are you using data from some other server? Also **please read the comments people make**, we dont make comments just for fun you know

Comment: i'm using data from other server

Comment: How/Why has the data you are trying to process suddenly changed?????

Comment: because i have added some your changes and i have request to server one file instead all file. The problem is the same but it is clearly to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

## Use this code to standardize json.

```
<?php
//also can get $input value from a file
//or
$input='{
    "status": 200,
    "msg": "OK",
    "result": {
       "72fA-_Lq8Ak3": {
            "id": "72fA-_Lq8Ak3",
            "status": 200,
            "name": "The quick brown fox.txt",
            "size": 123456789012,
            "sha1": "2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12",
            "content_type": "plain/text",
        },
        "72fA-_Lq8Ak4": {
            "id": "72fA-_Lq8Ak4",
            "status": 500,
            "name": "The quick brown fox.txt",
            "size": false,
            "sha1": "2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12",
            "content_type": "plain/text",
        },
        "72fA-_Lq8Ak5": {
            "id": "72fA-_Lq8Ak5",
            "status": 404,
            "name": false,
            "size": false,
            "sha1": false,
            "content_type": false,
        },
        "72fA-_Lq8Ak6": {
            "id": "72fA-_Lq8Ak6",
            "status": 451,
            "name": "The quick brown fox.txt",
            "size": 123456789012,
            "sha1": "2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12",
            "content_type": "plain/text",
        }
    }
}';
$output=preg_replace("/(\s*|),(\s*|)}((\s*|),|)/si","\n},",$input);
echo($output);
?>
```

---

## Output :

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "msg": "OK",
    "result": {
       "72fA-_Lq8Ak3": {
            "id": "72fA-_Lq8Ak3",
            "status": 200,
            "name": "The quick brown fox.txt",
            "size": 123456789012,
            "sha1": "2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12",
            "content_type": "plain/text"
},
        "72fA-_Lq8Ak4": {
            "id": "72fA-_Lq8Ak4",
            "status": 500,
            "name": "The quick brown fox.txt",
            "size": false,
            "sha1": "2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12",
            "content_type": "plain/text"
},
        "72fA-_Lq8Ak5": {
            "id": "72fA-_Lq8Ak5",
            "status": 404,
            "name": false,
            "size": false,
            "sha1": false,
            "content_type": false
},
        "72fA-_Lq8Ak6": {
            "id": "72fA-_Lq8Ak6",
            "status": 451,
            "name": "The quick brown fox.txt",
            "size": 123456789012,
            "sha1": "2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12",
            "content_type": "plain/text"
},
    }
}
```

Comment: i have already this output, the output that server returns to me (after the changes) is this: {"status":200,"msg":"OK","result":{"TgaB4CzkhaM":{"id":"TgaB4CzkhaM","status":200,"name":"esempio2.avi.mp4","size":"10391713","sha1":"125d4aa4c039cdf5686d565e705e38cbab966550","content_type":"video\/mp4","cstatus":"0"}}} how can i enter on "id":"TgaB4CzkhaM","status":200,"name":"esempio2.avi.mp4","size":"10391713","sha1":"125d4aa4c03?

Comment: John PLEASE add this stuff to your question. Nobody can read stuff like this in a comment

Comment: if this answer is useful , make its plus. @John

Answer (score 0):

## New Answer , For New Update

> how can i enter on results-> TgaB4CzkhaM -> status?

```
<?php
$input='{
    "status":200,
    "msg":"OK",
    "result":{
            "TgaB4CzkhaM":{ "id":"TgaB4CzkhaM",
                            "status":200,
                            "name":"esempio2.avi.mp4",
                            "size":"10391713",
                            "sha1":"125d4aa4c039cdf5686d565e705e38cbab966550",
                            "content_type":"video\/mp4",
                            "cstatus":"0"
                        }
            }
}';
$json=json_decode($input,true);
print_r($json);//this line for print json as array and optional , you can remove this line
if(isset($json["result"]["TgaB4CzkhaM"]["status"]))
{
    echo($json["result"]["TgaB4CzkhaM"]["status"]);
}
else
{
    echo("Error!");
}
```

**Output :**

```
Array
(
    [status] => 200
    [msg] => OK
    [result] => Array
        (
            [TgaB4CzkhaM] => Array
                (
                    [id] => TgaB4CzkhaM
                    [status] => 200
                    [name] => esempio2.avi.mp4
                    [size] => 10391713
                    [sha1] => 125d4aa4c039cdf5686d565e705e38cbab966550
                    [content_type] => video/mp4
                    [cstatus] => 0
                )

        )

)
200
```